# Simple algebra confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I have a simple algebra question which i can work out like the following
$$\begin{align}
    x - 8 & = x/3 + 1/6 \\
    6(x - 8) & = 6(x/3 + 1/6) \\
    6x - 48 & = 6x/3 + 6/6 \\
    6x - 48 & = 2x + 1 \\
    6x & = 2x + 49 \\
    4x & = 49 \\
    x & = 49/4
\end{align}$$

However, if I were to first remove the $8$ from the right hand side:
$$\begin{align}
    x - 8 & = x/3 + 1/6 \\
    x & = x/3 + 49/6 \\
    3x & = x + 49/6 \\
    2x & = 49/6 \\
\end{align}$$
How do I go from $2x = 49/6$ to $x = 49/4$?

I'm pretty confused so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correction is needed in the third step of your second argument:  $3x=x +\color{red}3\cdot 49/6$.

That is from the second step:
$$
x={x\over3}+{49\over 6}
$$
you multiply both sides by 3 (and on the right, the "*entire side*"):
$$
3\cdot x=3\cdot \bigl( {x\over3}+{49\over 6}\bigr)
$$to obtain
$$
 3x=  3\cdot{x\over3} +3\cdot{49\over 6} ,
$$
or
$$
 3x=  x + {49\over 2} ;
$$
which will give you the same solution as before, $x=49/4$.

Comment: Why is that? Could you please show me the correct steps involved.

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot.